# How to show image to datagridview from mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I have to create a window form that will bind to a MySQL table to DataGridView my DataGridView looks like this

```
ID     Name      PIC
1      Leo       64BaseStringImage
2      hello     64BaseStringImage
```

By using this code

```
mcon.Open();
MySqlDataAdapter MyDA = new MySqlDataAdapter();
string sqlSelectAll = "SELECT id,name,pic from stockitem ORDER BY id ASC, name ASC";
MyDA.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(sqlSelectAll, mcon);

DataTable table = new DataTable();
MyDA.Fill(table);

BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
bSource.DataSource = table;

this.dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
DataGridViewColumn column = dataGridView1.Columns[2];
column.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;

//dataGridView1.DataBindings.Add("Image", mbsPrimario, "PICFIELD", true, System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);

mcon.Close();
```

Is it possible to make the DataGridView become this?

```
ID   Name    PIC
1    Leo     Image
2    Hello   Image
```

I'm using this to decode image and success

```
Byte[] bitmapData = Convert.FromBase64String(FixBase64ForImage(abc));
System.IO.MemoryStream streamBitmap = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bitmapData);
def = new Bitmap((Bitmap)Image.FromStream(streamBitmap));
```

But I doesn't know how to get every string image, decode it and then insert back to Data source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way of show string to image is like this,

```
    private void MySQL_ToDatagridview4()
{
    dataGridView3.Columns.Clear();
    mcon.Close();
    mcon.Open();
    MySqlDataAdapter MyDA = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    string sqlSelectAll = "SELECT Item_Name,Item_Pic from stockitem ORDER BY Main_Category_ID ASC, Item_Name ASC";
    MyDA.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(sqlSelectAll, mcon);
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    MyDA.Fill(table);
    BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
    bSource.DataSource = table;
    this.dataGridView3.DataSource = bSource;
    DataGridViewImageColumn imageColumn = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
    imageColumn.HeaderText = "Pic";
    dataGridView3.Columns.Insert(0, imageColumn);
    for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            String pic = table.Rows[i]["Item_Pic"].ToString();
            Byte[] bitmapData = Convert.FromBase64String(FixBase64ForImage(pic));
            System.IO.MemoryStream streamBitmap = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bitmapData);
            def = new Bitmap((Bitmap)Image.FromStream(streamBitmap));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.StackTrace);
        }
        dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = def;
    }
    dataGridView3.Columns.Remove("Item_Pic");
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView3.Rows)
    {
        row.Height = 110;
    }
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView3.Columns)
    {
        col.Width = 110;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView3.ColumnCount; i++)
    {
        dataGridView3.Columns[i].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
        dataGridView3.AutoResizeColumns();
        dataGridView3.Columns[i].DefaultCellStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 8F, FontStyle.Bold);
    }
    mcon.Close();
}
```